# Customizing android status bar

Tags: android, adb, statusbar

I am a newbie to android app development. I want to customize my android status bar. I searched in web for this requirement, I saw a video on youtube, what i understood after watching that video is 1 file named framework-res.apk is responsible for status bar.

He is using adb pull command with file name framework-res.apk and doing something.

Can anybody explain what is that procedure. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with android development, its rather android hacking. :) 
But its really simple, you need root, pull framework-res.apk from device. extract it (7Zip or WinRar) and you have a huge amount of pngs's. You only have to edit them and repack the apk, sign it and push it to device and reboot. tadda

Comment: Are you trying to modify this bar when users use your app, or are you changing the status bar of the Android system?

Comment: I dont even think framework-res.apk is actually an apk in a phone...

Comment: then what it is ? please tell me clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you are trying to customize home screen? If that's the case I think you need to look at [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1442320).