# How does Xposed framework modify Android status bar?

Tags: android, root, xposed

An app in Xposed Framework named "Network Speed Indicator" can make net speed shown on android status bar. How to achieve this?

I looked up some other questions like this one[Customizing android status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050883/customizing-android-status-bar).It said "This has nothing to do with android development, its rather android hacking. :) But its really simple, you need root, pull framework-res.apk from device. extract it (7Zip or WinRar) and you have a huge amount of pngs's. You only have to edit them and repack the apk, sign it and push it to device and reboot. tadda".

Does xposed also do it this way?

Answer (score 0):

Xposed actually works in a more interesting way, it modifies `/system/bin/app_process` by adding a jar (`/data/data/de.robv.android.xposed.installer/bin/XposedBridge.jar` to be precise), which allows you to "hook" to any method call. Basically, you can run your own code before or after any method. Here's some example code from [the GitHub page](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/wiki/Development-tutorial):

```
package de.robv.android.xposed.mods.tutorial;

import static de.robv.android.xposed.XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.widget.TextView;
import de.robv.android.xposed.IXposedHookLoadPackage;
import de.robv.android.xposed.XC_MethodHook;
import de.robv.android.xposed.callbacks.XC_LoadPackage.LoadPackageParam;

public class Tutorial implements IXposedHookLoadPackage {
    public void handleLoadPackage(final LoadPackageParam lpparam) throws Throwable {
        if (!lpparam.packageName.equals("com.android.systemui"))
            return;

        findAndHookMethod("com.android.systemui.statusbar.policy.Clock", lpparam.classLoader, "updateClock", new XC_MethodHook() {
            @Override
            protected void afterHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                TextView tv = (TextView) param.thisObject;
                String text = tv.getText().toString();
                tv.setText(text + " :)");
                tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This hooks into the system UI clock update method and adds `:)` to the time, plus makes the text red. Hopefully this gives you some idea of how things work in Xposed.

The obious benefit is you're not replacing the original app, so no unzip-sign-push procedure is necessary. Just have the original app, Xposed framework and your module.

Edit: Also, just unzipping and replacing PNGs won't give you access to working code, which is why network speed in status bar is something that requires you to use Xposed - you have to "dig into" the code that creates the text that is shown in the status bar.

Comment: Thanks! It's much more clear after I went through the Development tutorial, but that how  the "hook" mechanism works still confuses me. I came to konw that hook is achieved in jni. Is there any other konwledge should I learn about to understand this mechanism?